# Audio capture through remote desktop connection for a VM

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, audio-recording

I have a Windows VM, on which I need to record voice. The issue is that I use a Remote Desktop connection to connect to it. Which RDC client should i use, so that my local machine can capture audio through the mic and send it to the VM. I have tried using 2X and mstsc. IS there a client that can do this.

Comment: What is your configuration? I think starting with Win7 (both client and server), input redirection is enabled: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154341(v=WinEmbedded.70).aspx

Comment: I was earlier using a Windows 7 machine to mstsc to an XP machine, which does not allow audio redirection for recording. With both machines Windows 7 this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: I will add this as a response. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 introduced input redirection. Connecting from Win 7 to Win XP does not support input redirection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154341(v=WinEmbedded.70).aspx